# What do $∂,∂$ and $∂$ individually mean?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

So, I came up with this *(weird)* warning paragraph in my [calc textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470647698):

> The symbol $∂z$, unlike the differential $dz$, has no meaning of it's own. For
> example if we were to "cancel" partial symbols in the chain-rule formula
>
> $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$
>
> we would obtain:
>
> $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$
>
> which is false in cases $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}≠0$.

I know that for variable $y$ dependent on $x$ in such a way that $y=f(x)$ we can say:
$dx=∆x$ and $dy=\lim_{∆x\rightarrow0}∆y$.

Analogously for the variable $z$ dependent on $x$ and $y$ in such a way that $z=f(x,y)$ can we say: $dx=∆x,dy=∆y$ and $dz=\lim_{(∆x,∆y)\rightarrow(0,0)}∆z$ $??$

Are $∂x=dx,∂y=dy$ and $∂z=dz$ $??$ If they are not, what do $∂z,∂x$ and $∂y$ individually mean$?$ And what does the differential $dz$ expresses?

*[I am probably sounding like a dumb econ undergrad (which I am) so mind my lack of mathematical knowledge.]*

Comment: “Has no meaning on its own.” If $\partial z=dz,$ why would we use different symbols? Your definition of $dy$ is really an intuition, not a definition, but  $dy$ can (sometimes) be treated like a value. The whole point of the book’s note is that $\partial y$ can’t be treated this way. (What $dy$ *is* can later be seen as a very subtle thing, but thinking of it as a kind of value is “good enough” for calculus.)

Comment: It would be wise to heed the correct text warning if you want to avoid easily preventable errors.

Answer (score 1):

If $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, the appropriate formula is

$$ \Delta z \approx \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \Delta x + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \Delta y$$

So we have $\dfrac{\Delta z}{\Delta x} \approx \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$  when $\Delta y = 0$, and $\dfrac{\Delta z}{\Delta y} \approx \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ when $\Delta x = 0$. $\partial z$ can't have a meaning of its own, because it would have to be different depending on whether $x$ or $y$ is changing.

Comment: Not sure how that helps distinguish the difference between $dx$ and $\partial x.$

Answer (score -2):

$\Delta$ is the Greek letter "Delta" which is often used to stand for "difference" - $\Delta x$ is a "difference in x" which is to say a small change from a given $x$.

$dx$ with a Latin small letter "d" is an "infinitesimal difference" where we take the limit of some expression as the small difference approaches 0.

$\delta x$ is a Greek letter delta again, but lowercase. It also means an infinitesimal difference, but by convention is used for derivatives in one of many input variables.

Comment: That doesn’t include $\partial x,$ the term in question. `\partial x` is neither delta nor $dx.$